# Cannot get concurrent SFTP users to log in

Tags: networking, server, ssh, sftp

I have a SFTP Ubuntu Server 16.04 in the DMZ, if one user logs in via WINSCP another user is unable to login in.

**SSHD Config**

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64)

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

I can post more info if needed, just not sure where to start, I think this is something that may have been done on the user or group level but I do not know where to make the appropriate changes.

EDIT- When attempting to connect with WINSCP I can only connect with 1 user at a time, I cannot connect with multiple users, I did add maxstartup 500 to the sshd _config.  I restarted the service and the issue still exists  Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[man sshd_config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html) specify two relevant parameters: `MaxSessions` and `MaxStartups`

> ```
>  MaxSessions
>          Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem
>          (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection.  Multiple
>          sessions may be established by clients that support connection
>          multiplexing.  Setting MaxSessions to 1 will effectively disable
>          session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all
>          shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting
>          forwarding.  The default is 10.
>
>  MaxStartups
>          Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated
>          connections to the SSH daemon.  Additional connections will be
>          dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime
>          expires for a connection.  The default is 10:30:100.
>
>          Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
>          three colon separated values “start:rate:full” (e.g. "10:30:60").
>          sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of
>          “rate/100” (30%) if there are currently “start” (10)
>          unauthenticated connections.  The probability increases linearly
>          and all connection attempts are refused if the number of
>          unauthenticated connections reaches “full” (60).
> ```

Comment: I seen that, since MaxSessions is not in the sshd_config and Max Startups is # out.    Is there a default it is prompting too, or do I need to add them in order for it to work properly?  I am just confused as to what it means when a line is not added versus commented out?   Also thank you for the help!

Comment: Also should I add both Max Sessions and Max Startups and in doing so do I need to add any other lines to allow each of those to function properly?